# How to edit Azure function code on Azure portal once the parameter WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE as been set to 1?

Tags: azure, powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I know this is not possible because of the parameter described in this message:

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

However, if I change the value of this parameter to 0, the code is still uneditable.
My Azure function is using a lot of libraries that I have to deploy everytime I update even a single character in the code.
This is really anoying. I would like to be able to edit my code without wasting 5 ou 10 minutes waiting for all libraries to be downloaded too.

Do I need to remake my Azure function and edit it only on Azure portal to keep the possibility to edit it ?

Is there a way to get the code back to editable status ?

Thank you.

Comment: Azure functions can be edited if and only if they are created in azure portal.If you don't want to deploy your app often then you can create a function app in portal.Suggestion - set up a local environment test out your changes and then push to cloud when you have bulk changes this will save you from the pain of deploying each and every time for a minor change.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you need to do is to delete the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

I noticed that when we deployed a Function app from local to azure, the app setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` would be added by default, which means your code file is in **read-only** mode, you can **not** edit it unless you delete the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`.

But it should work if you change the value to 0, because it works for me. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

MIcrosoft docs, [Run your functions from a package file in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#enable-functions-to-run-from-a-package), states the  valid values for `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` are either 1 or `<URL>`, not 0.  So rather than setting the value to 0, delete the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting completely.